# How to find the repeated elements in a vector

Tags: list-manipulation, scripting

Is there a way to write a function where the input is a vector and the output is the elements in the vector that are repeated?

I was trying to use something along the lines:

```
f[x_] := DeleteCases[Gather[x], Length[#1] != 1]
```

Of course this doesn't work, giving me this output:

```
input: f[{1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 5, 2, 7, 8, 9, 0, 11}] 
output: {{1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {4}, {3}, {5, 5}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {0}, {11}}
```

If I was able to delete the elements with Length 1, I could delete easily construct the output

Comment: Maybe `f[x_] := Select[Gather[x], Length[#] != 1 &][[All, 1]]`.

Answer (score 9):

[`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html) requires a [pattern](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html), not a function, as second argument:

```
f[x_] := DeleteCases[Gather[x], {_}]

f[{1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 5, 2, 7, 8, 9, 0, 11}]
(*    {{1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {5, 5}}    *)
```

Answer (score 8):

You may use [`Tally`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tally.html) and [`ConstantArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConstantArray.html).

With

```
lst = {1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 5, 2, 7, 8, 9, 0, 11}
```

and

```
repeatedElements[lst_List] := ConstantArray @@@ DeleteCases[Tally[lst], {_, 1}]
```

then

```
repeatedElements[lst]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {5, 5}}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

```
list = {1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 5, 2, 7, 8, 9, 0, 11};
```

#### `Gather` + `Cases`

```
ClearAll[duplicateElements1]
duplicateElements1 = Cases[{_, __}] @* Gather;

duplicateElements1 @ list
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {5, 5}}
> ```

#### [`Counts`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Counts.html) + [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) + [`KeyValueMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyValueMap.html):

```
ClearAll[duplicateElements2]
duplicateElements2 = KeyValueMap[ConstantArray] @* Select[GreaterThan @ 1] @* Counts;

duplicateElements2 @ list
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {5, 5}}
> ```

#### [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) + [`Values`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values.html)

```
ClearAll[duplicateElements3]
duplicateElements3 = Values @ GroupBy[#, Identity, If[Length@# > 1, #, Nothing] &] &;

duplicateElements3 @ list
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {5, 5}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`ResourceFunction["Duplicates"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/Duplicates/)

```
list = {1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 5, 2, 7, 8, 9, 0, 11};
Gather@ResourceFunction["Duplicates"]@list

(* result: {{1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {5, 5}} *)
```

And here's another way using undocumented function `` GeneralUtilities`FindDuplicates ``

```
With[{c = Counts@list},
 ConstantArray[#, c[#]] & /@ GeneralUtilities`FindDuplicates[list]
]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 5, 2, 7, 8, 9, 0, 11};

Cases[{_, __}] @ Map[Cases[list, Repeated @ #] &, DeleteDuplicates @ list]
```

{{1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {5, 5}}

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 5, 2, 7, 8, 9, 0, 11};
```

Using `SequenceCases`:

```
SequenceCases[Sort@#, s : {Repeated[x_, {2, ∞}]} :> s] &@list

(*{{1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {5, 5}}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

A rephrase of @Edmund's answer using `Table`:

```
list = {1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 5, 2, 7, 8, 9, 0, 11};
Tally[list] /. {_, 1} :> Nothing /. {a_, b_} :> Table[a, b]
```

or closer to OP's attempt:

```
(list // GatherBy[#, Count] &) /. {_} :> Nothing
```

---

> {{1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {5, 5}}